# How to make Google Chrome behave normaly again

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, windows-8.1

I'm using Windows 8 and I recently updated chrome as well as my entire system. Now whenever I click on the chrome Icon pinned to my taskbar instead of popping up a single window that is floating in the desktop, chrome grabs the entire screen, and when I hover near the bottom of it, it doesn't show my original desktop but some strange "chrome desktop" whcih includes the google chrome icon, gmail, and youtube to the bottom left.

I want to restore my chrome back to its original functionality which was a lot more efficient by allowing me to quickly move between windows

Comment: Agh I found the answer. The 'Relaunch Chrome in Desktop' Option

Comment: You could [Answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So using chrome in the top right side there should be a button that when clicked generates a menu (visited for managing plugins, apps, and history).

Near the bottom of it there is a 'Relaunch Chrome in Desktop' link that can be clicked to fix Chrome.